# Build custom Alpine linux ISO on other distro

Tags: alpine-linux

I want to make custom lightweight linux ISO for qemu, install python, some other packages.

I found out that alpine linux is offering that possibility through simple [script](https://github.com/alpinelinux/alpine-make-vm-image).
However, it spits out this message:

```
> apk not found, downloading static apk-tools
2020-04-21 18:14:17 URL:*big-url*apk-tools-2.10.4-x86_64-linux.tar.gz
 -> "apk-tools-2.10.4-x86_64-linux.tar.gz" [1]
apk-tools-2.10.4-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: ЦЕЛ

> Attaching image image.iso as a NBD device
WARNING: Image format was not specified for 'image.iso' and probing guessed raw.
         Automatically detecting the format is dangerous for raw images, write operations on block 0 will be restricted.
         Specify the 'raw' format explicitly to remove the restrictions.
```

And quits. Created ISO is not usable, i guess, it's empty. What am i doing wrong?

My wrapper script:

```
export PACKAGES="python3 chromium chromium-chromedriver
          setup-xorg-base xfce4 xfce4-terminal
          lightdm-gtk-greeter dbus-x11 sudo"
export IMAGE_SIZE="512M"

./alpine-make-vm-image --packages "$PACKAGES" image.iso -- ./additional_install.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had to explicitly state qemu image type via `--image-format` option

```
./alpine-make-vm-image --image-format qcow2
```